# how to save multiple column at one click in yii2

Tags: yii2

Sorry guys my title might not really explain what i want to achieve, i have an array of countries and i want to save it into the data base below is my code

```
public function actionCountries(){
    $countries = array("AF" => "Afghanistan",
    "AX" => "Åland Islands",
    "AL" => "Albania",
    "DZ" => "Algeria",
    "AS" => "American Samoa",
    "AD" => "Andorra",
    "AO" => "Angola",
    "AI" => "Anguilla",
    "AQ" => "Antarctica",
    "AG" => "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "AR" => "Argentina",
    "AM" => "Armenia",
    "AW" => "Aruba",
    "AU" => "Australia",
    "AT" => "Austria",
    "AZ" => "Azerbaijan",
    "BS" => "Bahamas",
    "BH" => "Bahrain",
    "BD" => "Bangladesh",
    "BB" => "Barbados",
    "YE" => "Yemen",
    "ZM" => "Zambia",
    "ZW" => "Zimbabwe");

    $model = new Country();
    foreach($countries as $code => $name){
       $model->code = $code
       $model->code = $name
       if($model->save()){
         echo $model->countryId;
       }
      }

}
```

i want to save all of the country into the database on one single click, but the result i got is empty, if i supply a false argument to the save() method i got the  last element of the array saved into the database like below

```
$model = new Country();
foreach($countries as $code => $name){
   $model->code = $code
   $model->code = $name
   if($model->save(false)){
     echo $model->countryId;
   }
  }
  this code will save only the last element in the array while the first code did nothing
```

Any help on this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because

```
$model = new Country();
```

is outside of the loop so you are saving the same model over and over again. Move this inside the loop.

By the way - it's not efficient. Take a look at [batchInsert()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#non-select-queries) method for more memory-friendly way to do it.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but i move $model = new Country(); to within the loop but still not working,

Comment: Thanks it work now, i moved it within the loop and pass a FALSE argument to the save() method.